# Salesforce Reports & Dashboard Sharing

Tags: salesforce-id, dashboard, reports-folder

We have to give permission to user to Save report and Dashboards in a public Folder but users should not be allowed to Edit, Move or delete Reports/Dashboards which falls under that public folder.

How to achieve this ?

I have shared the public folder with Edit permission so user can able to add their reports/Dashboard in it. But with this users can also able to Edit, Move or delete Reports/Dashboards which falls under that public folder which we don't want.

Comment: Did you check profile permissions of the user? Maybe they have access to manage reports or they have modify all data?

Comment: No they don't have any such permission.

Comment: Users are just having these two permissions:
1. Create and Customize Reports
2. Create and Customize Dashboards